# Michael Hartl Chapter 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

so I'm going thru the current version of the ror guide. My app has been running fine, but when i change my code as suggested in the beginning of chapter 5, I get an error that says

> ```
> "undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x000001062c30d8>:0x000001064a1148>"
> ```

Is there anyone who could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code

Before:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

and After

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                                           'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Home",   '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Help",   '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your `def full_title` from `application_helper`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have defined a helper function `full_title` in your `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` check if it's there, if not then define it like this :

```
def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{page_title} | #{base_title}"
    end
  end
```